# Put 'nix box to sleep from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, terminal, sleep

What command(s) do I type in the terminal to put the computer to sleep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2014 update :**
`systemctl suspend` should work on all OSs using systemd.

**Old version :**

`/etc/acpi/sleep.sh` or `pm-suspend`.

Comment: this also works on Fedora (FC-18, FC-19): `systemctl suspend`

Comment: I added that to the answer.