# How can you hibernate/suspend using the command line in linux?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Put 'nix box to sleep from command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/225315/put-nix-box-to-sleep-from-command-line)

I found that the solution was to do:

```
pmi action hibernate
```

But when I typed in that, it showed:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:
 The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
```

I couldn't go further from here. Please help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu there's a script which is part of the pm-utils package - `/usr/sbin/pm-suspend` which can be used to suspend from the command line.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

Additionally there is `pm-hibernate` to hibernate to disk and `pm-suspend-hybrid` to do a combined hibernate/suspend.

Answer (score 3):

The low level way would be

```
echo -n mem > /sys/power/state
```

or for suspend-to-disk (hibernate)

```
echo -n disk > /sys/power/state
```

The available modes can be found by

```
cat /sys/power/state
```